# How to deploy "Google Sign-In for Websites" with a google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-signin

Getting error after trying to implement the sample "[Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)".  I think the issue is that this is a "Google Apps Script" and OAuth 2.0 client IDs do not allow a **path**... See the following:

> Authorized JavaScript origins
>   For use with requests from a browser. This is the origin URI of the client application. It can't contain a wildcard (https://*.example.com) or a path (https://example.com/subdir). If you're using a nonstandard port, you must include it in the origin URI.

Google Apps Scripts are all *https://script.google.com/a/...domain.../macros/s/...id.../exec*

Here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="[ the app id ].apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
  <script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried creating a new OAuth 2.0 client ID apart from the default Apps Script ID in my cloud console (as suggested by [Bitz Trail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10714966/bitz-trail)), however, I don't see "Authorized callback urls" in either the Apps Script ID credentials or the the OAuth client for entering either of these

https://script.google.com/oauthcallback

https://script.google.com/d/projectid/usercallback

I have tried every combination I can think of.

Any additional instructions would be greatly appreciated - very new to this, so I feel I am just missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: You still haven't said anything about or described  the error. Provide [mcve]

Comment: Well, I thought it was pretty clear...  I wanted to know if anyone has actually successfully done this with a "google-apps-script" because it would appear that from the OAuth2 documentation (that I included in the description) states wildcards or paths - and ANY google-apps-script has a path (subfolders) in the URL...

But since you need an error...

The heading says "Error 400 (OAuth2 Error)!!1"
400. That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The JavaScript origin in the request, https://...script.googleusercontent.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. etc.

Comment: Let me know if I need to add this in the actual "Question"...  happy to do whatever you need...

Comment: Add the error to the question. You don't need to add paths. Just add `google.com` as well as `googleusercontent.com` to authorized domains